# Вывод одного значения из mysqli query SELECT с условием

Tags: php, html, sql

Мне нужно выводить логин учителя из базы учеников каждую итерацию цикла. Проблема в том, что разные функции воспринимают этот запрос по разному - как объект или булиновое значение

```
<?php
$teacherquery = "SELECT `teacher` FROM `users` WHERE login = $student";
    $resultteacher = mysqli_query($conn, $sqluser);
?>
```

Выводит как булиновое значение. Как вывести значение которое находится в базе данных? 
До этого я перерыл весь стаковерфлоу на английском и не нашёл ответа - проблемы были похожие, но не точь в точь. Отсутствовало условие WHERE или брали целый массив данных, а не как у меня - одно значение с одним условием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ из бд нужно преобразовать в массив с помощью fetch_array или, в случае выборки нескольких записей, fetch_all.

Например:

Подключение бд.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "bd_name");
```

Делаем сам запрос.

```
$resultteacher = $mysqli->query("SELECT `teacher` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". $student ."'");
```

Проверяем выбрало ли хоть что-то и преобразовываем в массив.

```
if ($resultteacher->num_rows != 0) {
    $teachers_array = $resultteacher->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Теперь наш ответ из БД спрятан в

```
$teachers_array['teacher']
```

Если же мы использовали fetch_all, то в

```
$teachers_array[0]['teacher']
```

И еще, не нужно делать запросы циклом, это очень плохо влияет на производительность БД в целом. Учите sql и делайте развернутый запрос с выборкой всех нужных записей.

Comment: Да, стоит поучить SQL п о з ж е, у меня школьный проект горит и я всего лишь школьник с базовыми знаниями SQLi, не совсем понимаю что в нём что. Большое спасибо, очень выручили, сдавать то скоро) Два дня поиска и своих попыток решились всего за час. Да и это всего лишь школьный проект, производительность совсем не важна, но спасибо за поправку.